# react-native webview localfile

Tags: android, react-native, webview

**Problem:**

I should display offline a Html page stored in my react-native app, and for to do it I used WebView:

```
<WebView
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   source = {{uri:'file:///android_asset/index.html'}}
 />
```

but it load just html file without css and/or js, this is an example of my html page:

> my file html is stored in: react-native-project->android->app->src->main->assets->web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body >
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

this is an example of my css page:

> my file css is stored in: react-native-project->android->app->src->main->assets->web->css

```
h1 {
  color:red;
}
```

I have found [this post on medium](https://medium.com/@snehabagri.90/reactnative-webview-with-local-content-c98a09340801) but not work for my and BaseUrl not work.

**Question:**

How I can display a Html page with relative file css and js connected to it offline on react-native?

can I use the cache how do [react-native-offline-cache-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline-cache-webview) ?

**Thanks for your attention and sorry if my English is wrong but I'm not a native speaker bye**

Comment: I had to build all JS, CSS and HTML into a single HTML file. I then copy the single file to `./android/app/src/main/assets/` and reference it via `"file:///android_asset/index.html"`

Comment: Just to further my comment, I used Webpack to bundle the files. Also, you only need to reference `file:///android_asset...` when you're running on Android and you are NOT in developer mode.

Comment: Hi @Dan, thanks for the help but how i can do for the tag img, example: <img src='what i write here?'/>